# Remove weekends from a date range in PHP

Tags: calendar

I need to create a calendar showing holidays booked by staff so need to remove weekends from any date range where the booking goes across a weekend
This creates a list of dates from  the start date to end date of a booking.
How do I print out just working days being requested?

```
$datediff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$datediff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
for($i = 0; $i < $datediff + 1; $i++){
    $dates= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . 'day'));
}
```

Comment: May be this link can help you http://daveismyname.com/show-working-days-of-a-month-excluding-weekends-with-php-bp#.VUh03OSY55c'

Comment: Thanks Sunil, pointed me in the right direction tho can see needs some work to adapt it to exactly what I need